# Create a view in SQL Server 2014 that combines three queries each with a different where statements

Tags: sql-server, view

I am trying to create one output using a view that would combine the quotes from Query 2 with the quotes from Query 1 and the policies from Query 3 with the policies from Query 1.  Query 1 is my main query ... 2 and 3 would be left joined.

Query 1:

```
SELECT
    A.AgencyId,
    SUM(A.Quotes) AS Quotes,
    SUM(A.NB) AS Policies,
    CONVERT(DATE, A.Date) AS Date,
    C.WeekEndDate
FROM
    dbo.Agent_Qts_Daily A
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.AgentList B ON A.AgencyID = B.AgencyID
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.WE_DATES C ON A.Date = C.Date
WHERE 
    Year = '2016'
GROUP BY
    A.AgencyID, A.Date, C.WeekEndDate
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    B.AgencyID,
    SUM(A.Quote_Cnt) AS Quotes,
    CONVERT(DATE, A.DateRecd) AS Date,
    C.WeekEndDate
FROM
    dbo.TestData A
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.AgentList B ON A.AgtID = B.AGTID
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.WE_DATES C ON A.DateRecd = C.Date
WHERE
    A.FirmGroup <> 'ABC'
    AND A.Source = 'DEF'
    AND C.Year = '2016'
GROUP BY
    B.AgencyID, A.DateRecd, C.WeekEndDate
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT
    B.AgencyID,
    SUM(A.sold_Cnt) AS Policies,
    CONVERT(DATE, A.DateBound) AS Date,
    C.WeekEndDate
FROM
    dbo.TestData A
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.AgentList B ON A.AgtID = B.AGTID
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.WE_DATES C ON A.DateBound = C.Date
WHERE
    A.FirmGroup <> 'ABC'
    AND A.sold_Cnt = '1'
    AND A.Source = 'DEF'
    AND C.Year = '2016'
GROUP BY
    B.AgencyID, A.DateBound, C.WeekEndDate
```

Comment: What's the problem? You have the three subqueries, you have the logic to do the joins, you have all.

Comment: Just saying what you want to do isn't a question.   What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this or you can also use an sp to meet the same criteria

```
CREATE VIEW ViewName
AS
SELECT
  A.AgencyId,
  SUM(A.Quotes) AS Quotes,
  SUM(A.NB) AS Policies,
  CONVERT(DATE, A.Date) AS Date,
  C.WeekEndDate
FROM
  dbo.Agent_Qts_Daily A
  INNER JOIN dbo.AgentList B ON A.AgencyID = B.AgencyID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.WE_DATES C ON A.Date = C.Date
WHERE Year = '2016'
GROUP BY
  A.AgencyID,
  A.Date,
  C.WeekEndDate


  UNION ALL


  SELECT
  B.AgencyID,
  SUM(A.Quote_Cnt) AS Quotes,
  0 AS Policies,
  CONVERT(DATE, A.DateRecd) AS Date,
  C.WeekEndDate
FROM
  dbo.TestData A
  INNER JOIN dbo.AgentList B ON A.AgtID = B.AGTID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.WE_DATES C ON A.DateRecd = C.Date
WHERE
  A.FirmGroup <> 'ABC'
  AND A.Source = 'DEF'
  AND C.Year = '2016'
GROUP BY
  B.AgencyID,
  A.DateRecd,
  C.WeekEndDate

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  B.AgencyID,
  0 AS Quotes,
  SUM(A.sold_Cnt) AS Policies,
  CONVERT(DATE, A.DateBound) AS Date,
  C.WeekEndDate
FROM
  dbo.TestData A
  INNER JOIN dbo.AgentList B ON A.AgtID = B.AGTID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.WE_DATES C ON A.DateBound = C.Date
WHERE
  A.FirmGroup <> 'ABC'
  AND A.sold_Cnt = '1'
  AND A.Source = 'DEF'
  AND C.Year = '2016'
GROUP BY
  B.AgencyID,
  A.DateBound,
  C.WeekEndDate
```

Comment: The above isn't summing the three queries together correctly.  If there are 'AgencyIDs' in query 2 but not query 1, will the data for these agents still show in my final results?